# Unable to install Multicorn on mac

Tags: python, xcode, macos, multicorn

I am trying to install Multicorn on mac os 10.13 by cloning the repo. in my machine, but getting error, Also I have installed xcode for the  mac os 10.13.

```
➜  Multicorn git:(master) ✗ make && make install
```

**Error i am getting:**

Python version is 2.7
clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2  -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7  -I. -I./ -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/internal -I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.2/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o src/errors.o src/errors.c
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from src/errors.c:15:
In file included from src/multicorn.h:1:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: fatal error:
      'stdio.h' file not found
include 
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/errors.o] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same question and do this to solve the problem.

```
export CPATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/
```